# Django form with variable type

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How would you make a price field in Django form? The input could be either price (float) or value from select (for free, offer, by agreement, etc). In database, it's stored in FloatField (negative values has special meaning). Is there a way to make it through Django form model?

Comment: You should not hold all this in one column as it is not explicit

Comment: So you would add a ChoiceField to the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

One way would be to add and additional field to the model form to show the choices (price/free/offer/by agreement), then before saving the submitted information, look to see one of those choices was selected. If it has been selected, save the appropriate negative value in the price instead of what was entered in the price field.

As iklinac said, you'll probably wish you hadn't done it this way at some point in the future.